# How do I insert the same line into multiple files using VIM

Tags: vim

I would like to insert lines across multiple files the same way i can search and replace across multiple files.  For example, in order to search and replace the same string across 4 files I would do this (with multiple files open):

```
:115s/fidget/widget/|:wn|:115s/fidget/widget/|:wn|:115s/fidget/widget/|:wn|:115s/fidget/widget/|:wq
```

How would I insert a line instead of search & replace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert a line by doing a replace like so:

```
:115/$/\rfoo/
```

However lets kick this up a notch with `:windo`:

```
:windo 115s/$/\rfoo/
```

`:windo {cmd}` will execute `{cmd}` on each window.

Substitutions not your thing or have your text in a register?  Then use `:put`. Example of putting a line after line 115 from register `"a`:

```
:windo 115put a
```

Have more a bunch of files and don't want to be bothered with windows? Then use `:args` and :argdo`.

```
:args `find . -name '*.foo'
:argdo 115put a
```

There are a few related [Vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/) episodes that might be of intrest:

- [Meet the arglist](http://vimcasts.org/e/41)
- [Populating the arglist](http://vimcasts.org/e/42)
- [Using :argdo to change multiple files](http://vimcasts.org/e/43)
- [Project-wide find and replace](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/project-wide-find-and-replace/)

For more help see:

```
:h :s
:h :windo
:h :pu
:h :args
:h :argdo
```

Comment: `:bufdo` can be useful too. :)